# Gray background in a input field makes cursor invisible

Tags: html, css

When using gray background with input fields, all cursors become completely invisible. I'm quite new to html/css and I could not find any way to fix it.

```css
input, textarea {

  background-color: gray; 

}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<br /><br />
<textarea></textarea>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="button" />
```

Comment: Visible on my computer. Linux+Firefox or Linux+Chrome. What is your env?

Comment: It looks okay to me in Chrome v103. Which browser are you using?

Comment: It's the browser you're using, try a different browser and see the difference

Comment: @Normal I tried on both Chrome v103, and my OperaGX from what i see has Chrome/102.0. Both has invisible cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `caret-color` css prop. This will change the color of your `caret` making it more visible.

```css
input,
textarea {
  background-color: gray;
  caret-color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<br /><br />
<textarea></textarea>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="button" />
```

Comment: I'm not talking about the caret, all type of cursors are invisible. In this case, the text cursor.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on Chrome v103

Comment: I can't tell what is wrong, tested on Chrome v103 and it still is invisible. Thanks for testing.

Comment: What about firefox? Is it visible there?

Comment: Yep, also not visible on firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply some styles to your cursor using `caret-color:`:

```
.example1 {
  caret-color: red;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_caret-color.asp

However, when you try to build a website or using HTML/CSS try to know if it is available for all the browsers:
https://caniuse.com/?search=caret

Comment: Great, but the OP did not ask how to change the cursor color, it's most likely a browser problem

Comment: it's not me who downvoted